# How to create animations

Tags: android, animation

In the android support library there is a `NavigationDrawerToggle`.  When you open the drawer, it transforms into an arrow pointing towards the closing direction of the drawer using a rather nice animation. How can I create similar animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing animation you need to make anim xml file and write it yourself, but for this you don't need to make it. Here see a good example [here](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/12/16/android-lollipop-navigation-drawer-animation-support/).

Comment: I meant if there is a way to create an animation like that one by myself. I know how to use this.